# How to draw a rectangular cuboid with nodes on both sides

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could someone please help me to produce a pair of the following pair of objects: on the left hand side we have a rectangular cuboid (2x3x3 ''cube'')  with nodes on both sides connected by dashed lines and on the right hand side the cuboid is sliced into two parts (and nodes are also connected with dashed lines) [image]

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a#1{\begin{scope}[yslant=0.7]
\draw[dotted] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (2,2);
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\foreach \x in {0,1,2}{\foreach \y in {0,1,2}{
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] (n-#1\x\y)at (\x,\y){};}}
\end{scope}}\a{a}\begin{scope}[shift={(2.5cm,0)}]\a{b}\end{scope}
\foreach \x in {0,2}{\foreach \y in {0,2}{\draw (n-a\x\y) --(n-b\x\y);}}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]\a{c}\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=7.5cm]\a{d}\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is more verbose (just for comparison):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={inner sep=1pt,fill,outer sep=0,circle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line width=0.5pt,x=2cm,baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
  \foreach \x/\y/\z/\a in {0/0/0/1,0/1/0/2,1/1/0/3,1/0/0/4,0/0/1/5,0/1/1/6,1/1/1/7,1/0/1/8} {
    \coordinate (\a) at (\x,\y,\z);
    }

   \foreach \x/\y/\z/\a in  {0/0/0.5/11,0/1/0.5/21,0/0.5/0/31,0/0.5/1/41,
                     0/0.5/0.5/51,1/0/0.5/61,1/1/0.5/71,1/0.5/0/81, 1/0.5/1/91,1/0.5/0.5/101} {
    \coordinate (\a) at (\x,\y,\z);
    }


 \draw  (2) -- (3) -- (4);
 \draw (5) -- (6) -- (7) -- (8) -- cycle;
 \draw   (2) -- (6) (3) -- (7) (4) -- (8);

 \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}{
     \node[mynode] at (\x) {};
 }

 \draw[dashed]  (1) -- (2)
        (1) -- (4)
        (1) -- (5);


 \draw[dashed] (11) -- (21)
                (31)--(41)
                (61) -- (71)
                (81) -- (91);


 \foreach \x in {11,21,...,101}{
     \node[mynode] at (\x) {};
 }

\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line width=0.5pt,x=2cm,baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
  \foreach \x/\y/\z/\a in {0/0/0/1,0/1/0/2,1/1/0/3,1/0/0/4,0/0/1/5,0/1/1/6,1/1/1/7,1/0/1/8} {
    \coordinate (\a) at (\x,\y,\z);
    }

   \foreach \x/\y/\z/\a in  {0/0/0.5/11,0/1/0.5/21,0/0.5/0/31,0/0.5/1/41,
                     0/0.5/0.5/51,1/0/0.5/61,1/1/0.5/71,1/0.5/0/81, 1/0.5/1/91,1/0.5/0.5/101} {
    \coordinate (\a) at (\x,\y,\z);
    }


 \draw  (1) -- (5) -- (6) -- (2) -- cycle;
 \draw (4) -- (8) -- (7) -- (3) -- cycle;

 \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}{
     \node[mynode] at (\x) {};
 }

 \draw[dashed] (11) -- (21)
                (31)--(41)
                (61) -- (71)
                (81) -- (91);


 \foreach \x in {11,21,...,101}{
     \node[mynode] at (\x) {};
 }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just another option which uses percusse's code adapted to `pics`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{plane/.pic={
    \begin{scope}[yslant=0.7]
        \draw[dotted] (-1,-1) grid[step=1cm] (1,1);
        \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {-1,0,1}{
            \foreach \y in {-1,0,1}{
                \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] (\x\y)at (\x,\y){};
            }
        }
    \end{scope}
    }
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw pic (a) {plane};
\draw pic (b) at (3,0) {plane};
\draw pic (c) at (7.5,0) {plane};
\draw pic (d) at (10.5,0) {plane};

\draw (a-1-1)--(b-1-1) (a-11)--(b-11) (a1-1)--(b1-1) (a11)--(b11);

\draw[-latex, shorten >=1cm,shorten <=1cm] (b00)--(c00);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]